# No visible @interface for 'FirstViewController' declares the selector 'setUIImage'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

first i want to say i have searched for an answer to this error, but none of the answers seems to fit me.

what i am trying to do is pass an uiimage from one vc to another, this is the code that "should" do it. But i get the error "No visible @interface for 'FirstViewController' declares the selector 'setUIImage'"

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ImageEdit"])
    {

        FirstViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setUIImage:image];
    }
}
```

Comment: saad, the answer you gave me worked fine! thank you! post it again so i can give you +1.

Answer (score 0):

In the interface file for the destinationViewController, do:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject *uIImage;
```

and in the implementation file for the destinationViewController, do:

```
@synthesize uIImage;
```

HTH